# Firefox unable to launch in VM machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, grid, geckodriver

I am using below code for Firefox launch in locally and through VM machine. But I am unable to launch firefox through VM machine.

```
 case FIREFOX:
                    browserType = BrowserTypes.FIREFOX;
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                   firefoxOptions.setCapability("marionette", true);
                    firefoxOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
                    if(isRemote) {
                        webDriver = launchGridDriver(firefoxOptions, configProps.getNodeUrl());
                        Reporter.log("Running test on Grid, in browser \'Firefox\'", true);
                    } else {
                        webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
                        Reporter.log("Running test in browser \'FIREFOX\'", true);
                    }
                    break;


 private WebDriver launchGridDriver(Capabilities capabilities, String url){
        try{
            return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url), capabilities);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Reporter.log("There was an error setting up the remote WebDriver.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am able to launch firefox locally and when I just trying to launch in remote below error is getting.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "server:CONFIG_UUID": "02c53809-74d8-4b47-95a1-fc97610ba78c",
    "moz:firefoxOptions": {
      "args": [
      ],
      "prefs": {
      }
    },
    "marionette": true,
    "acceptInsecureCerts": true
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "moz:firefoxOptions": {
          "args": [
          ],
          "prefs": {
          }
        },
        "server:CONFIG_UUID": "02c53809-74d8-4b47-95a1-fc97610ba78c"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the complete path to the geckodriver.exe in this line
`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "Drivers/geckodriver.exe");`

Comment: @AnonymousFox : We added driver exe file into our project. So this is our complete path.

Answer (score 0):

Need Few more inputs.. It looks like the networking issue where your code host is unable to reach the Hub.

Please let me know that :-

1. Where is the hub VM located, If it is on same machine, do use the IP Bridge Configuration and not NAT.
2. Do your machine having code and having Hub are on same VLAN.
3. Where is the Node? You wont be seeing the browser launch on Hub. It will be on node.
4. getNodeUrl() returns the IP of hub machine.
5. Firewalls on the hub and node and the code host machine is off (Just to ensure it is not blocking the connection)

Rest code looks fine.

Comment: I am using IP bridge configuration for running scripts in remote. Hub and node sits in other machine and I am able to launch chrome and IE successfully in that machine. I am facing only issue with firefox.